# Posting an iframe with php

Tags: php, post, iframe

I am having problems sending an iframe code. The [src] parameter is deleted after sending. Codes and preview as follows.

Php:

```
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
    echo $_POST['frame'];
}
```

Html:

```
<form method="post">
    <input value="<iframe src='https://jsfiddle.net/'></iframe>" type="text" name="frame">
    <button name="post" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Display output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y21a.png)

Comment: Why do you want the iframe tag as a value inside the input field? There must be a better way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: not sure what you want to do save the ifame code?
`<form method="post">
    <input value="&lt;iframe src='https://jsfiddle.net/'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;" type="text" name="frame">
    <button name="post" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`

Comment: There is no such thing. The same problem still occurs when you submit it in a normal way.

Comment: The problem is solved when I remove [https] but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

form.php

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://www.jsfiddle.net/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

show.php

```
<iframe src="form.php"></iframe>
```

it isn't a perfect solution, but I think it is the best for this situation. Some sites you won't run into the problems you discussed.

Comment: Thank you. But that did not work. When I post, I want to see it on the same page.